# What does "$\overline{G}_*$ is the residue of $G_*$ in $\mathscr{O}_P(F)$" mean in Fulton's book on algebraic curves?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I'm trying to understand this phrase in [Fulton's algebraic curves](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf) book page 53:

[image]

Anyone could help me?

Thanks

Comment: It probably means the image in $\mathcal{O}_P(F)/m_p(F)$.

Comment: @AlexYoucis Can you explain a little bit more why this is the image in $\mathcal{O}_P(F)/m_P(F)$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I mean, it's just from context. The residue field is the field $\mathcal{O}_p/m_p$, so the residue of some element $f\in\mathcal{O}_p$ is likely its image in the residue field.